# django - disable staticfiles logging

Tags: django, static

noob question:

I want to disable logging on static assets on the console, I only want to see normal http requests (but not the ones for static files).

I always get this on the console for all the static file loading

```
[24/Sep/2014 22:18:55] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 39816
[24/Sep/2014 22:18:55] "GET /static/2.5.11/socialschools/css/molengo/molengo-regular-webfont.css HTTP/1.1" 200 509
[24/Sep/2014 22:18:55] "GET /static/2.5.11/socialschools/js/less.1.7.0.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 101854
[24/Sep/2014 22:18:55] "GET /static/2.5.11/socialschools/js/html5shiv.3.7.0.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2428
[24/Sep/2014 22:18:55] "GET /static/2.5.11/socialschools/js/jquery.1.9.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 92629
[24/Sep/2014 22:18:55] "GET /static/2.5.11/socialschools/js/respond.1.4.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4377
[24/Sep/2014 22:18:55] "GET /static...
```

Is there any way to disable this?

For example in express (nodejs), if I put the logging middleware before the static middleware, it doesn't log the static files. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I see that this question is pretty old (4 years and 8 months) I'd like to add possible solutions for that task. Since logging on static assets on the console is governed by the logging module, the answer is in logging configurations.
There is a concept of [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.filter) in python logging, which allows `record` to be passed further by loggers chain, or be suppressed simply by returning Boolean True or False.

I've got this problem a few times, so I'd like to put a solution here:

1. Let's write a Filter in `somemodule`.

```
from logging import Filter

class SkipStaticFilter(Filter):
    """Logging filter to skip logging of staticfiles"""
    def filter(self, record):
        return not record.getMessage().startswith('GET /static/')
```

**Edit:** For Django 2.2: replace `GET /static/` with `HTTP GET /static/`

2. Now let's add this filter into the settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    # Definition of filters
    'filters': {    
        'hide_staticfiles': {    
            '()': 'somemodule.SkipStaticFilter'    
        }
    },
    'version': 1,    
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,    
    'handlers': {    
        'console': {    
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',

            # Usage of that filter
            'filters': ['hide_staticfiles']    
        },    
    },    
    'loggers': {    
        'django': {
            # Usage of the handler with our filter  
            'handlers': ['console'],   
        }    
    },    

}
```

Now you will not see any log record which starts with `"GET /static/`
You can add more filters, with sophisticated rules to decide if you want to see that record or not (Do not hide the static requests if they are 404, for example)

Hope that would help someone to get rid of logging pollution.

Comment: Thanks, @Alex
In my case, I had to change the condition a bit (Django 4.2) as it starts with a `"`

    `return not record.getMessage().startswith('"GET /static')`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `runserver` command doesn't respect the `--verbosity` option that other management commands do.

For more information on the `--verbosity` option, check out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#displaying-debug-output

The core developers have marked the bug as "wontfix": https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15132

Comment: shouldn't something like this be solvable with a logging configuration and maybe a special filter?

Comment: If you can make it work, I'm sure the community would be very appreciative.